# Meu personagem segue o mouse, mas fica girando de ponta cabeça

Tags: construct-2

Meu personagem se movimenta ('voa') seguindo o mouse, mas ele fica a todo momento virando para os lados ou de ponta-cabeça. Alguém sabe como resolver isso? (para ele permanecer em pé, como é a sprite)?

Quando troco o Set angle toward por Set position (imagem abaixo), o Player para de girar de ponta cabeça, mas aí ele fica se movimentando (seguindo o mouse) muito rápido, ignorando a Behavior de bullet (que está no speed 40).

As Behaviors que o Player tem são: BoundToLayout + Bullet + Solid.

Faz dois dias que tento resolver isso, então agradeço muito se alguém puder me ajudar.

[image: Eventos e ações para o player seguir o mouse]

Comment: Olá. Se você fornecer um link com um [Exemplo Mínimo Completo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), facilitaria muitíssimo que alguém conseguisse te ajudar. Caso contrário, as pessoas precisarão ficar adivinhando o possível problema do seu jogo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como o personagem tem o *behavior* **Bullet** ativado, acredito que uma solução possível seja utilizar o método `Set angle of motion` (desse *behavior*), ao invés do `Set angle toward` do personagem.

O parâmetro informado na chamada do método é o ângulo entre o objeto e o cursor do mouse:

`angle(Self.X, Self.Y, Mouse.X,Mouse.Y)`

- Na ação do personagem, fica da seguinte forma:

[image: Chamada do método Set angle of motion]

- Para que não haja rotação do objeto durante o movimento, a propriedade `Set angle` do *behavior* *Bullet* deve ter o valor `No`:

[image: behavior Set angle]

- Com essas alterações, o resultado fica assim:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Olá, @Gomiero. Obrigado pela ajuda! Era exatamente o que eu precisava.
Valeu! :)

Comment: @AilsonBezerra marque a resposta como aceita então para dar como encerrado essa pergunta.